# htaccess and favicons

Tags: htaccess

I see from the Craft's default remove index.php htaccess code [here](https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php) that the following line takes into account favicon.ico files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
```

I was wondering, with the many different file names of favicons these days would it be ok to make the rule look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*\.ico|.*\.png)$ [NC]
```